# MMC snapin console not working

Tags: 2013-sp1, mmc

We observed that MMC snapin console is not working on either of our environments. The problem is that if we change timeouts on database connections, it will not change config file.

So, when we need to change config files, we need to go through process of decryption of file, changing data and encrypting it via IIS.

I was wondering has anyone found a way to fix/reinstall MMC?

Comment: try with MTS or from user who installed it

Answer (score 1):

The account you are using does not have the rights to change the settings.

To fix this:

- Log in to the CMS machine with the account that you used when you
  installed it
- Run a powershell as Administrator for each user account

  ```
  # Add RSA-Key
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe 
      -pa "TridionRsaKeyContainer" "domainname\cmills"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can just copy/paste MMC from a machine where it is working to the one where it isn't and that should be it. You can delete the one which isn't working and paste the one which is working. You will definitely need to do a machine restart for changes to take effect and this should resolve the issue.  Hope this helps